# How to split a column containing two divs on top of each other to the div's being side by side on smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly inexperienced in CSS, HTML and bootstrap.

Basically I would like to know how to split a single column on a large screen, into two columns on smaller screen so that the columns two div's sit side by side instead of on top of each other when the window is resized.

```
<div class= "container-fluid">
 <div class ="row">
  <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12"> 
   <canvas width="800" height="450">

   </canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
   <div id="Pseudo">

   </div>
   <div id="Element">

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want the `Pseudo` and `element divs` to sit next to each other on smaller devices and on top of each other on larger. Its working fine on a large screen.

I'm not sure if I can do that using bootstrap, I have been trying for a long time but having no luck.

Comment: Trying to add more information, but i'm new to stack overflow and its saying i have put code that is not properly formatted. Not sure why, I have indented 4 times for code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define single columns for your element, because defining the external column for both of them is not going to give you the result you are looking for. So, I think that something like this could do the trick:

```css
#Pseudo {
  background-color: red;
}

#Element {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class= "container-fluid">
 <div class ="row">
  <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-9 "> 
   <canvas width="800" height="450">
   </canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-3">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" id="Pseudo">
      x
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" id="Element">
      y
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is sort of what i would like, except for when the screen is large i would like the Pseudo and element div's to sit on top of each other.  
 
That does produce the desired result just need to change a few thing, thank you!

Comment: I tried locally over my browser, when it is under 900px if I got it right, it will show one each other, but after 900px, it just goes one up and one down because it is declared that for greater equal to large screen it needs to take all the column. What happens in your screen?

Answer (score 0):

From your code you are not doing anything to make the `Pseudo and element divs` dynamic.

It's funny because what you are trying to achieve is correct from the perspective of:

```
   <canvas width="800" height="450">
   </canvas>
```

and

```
   <div id="Pseudo">
   </div>
   <div id="Element">
   </div>
```

These two parts are dynamic. So the same way you implemented this for them you should implement for these divs.

Something like this:

```
<div class ="row">

<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
   <div id="Pseudo">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
   <div id="Element">
   </div>
</div>

</div>
```

And you don't have to worry about the others. Bootstrap accepts nested rows.